# How to set default time in bootstrap datetime picker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap datetime picker to display calender, when I select the date in the calender I want to set my time to to 00:00 hours:minutes on the selected date.

this is my script

```
<script>
      $(function() {
         `enter code here`$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
         language: 'en',
         setTime: '00:00 AM'
        });
      });
</script>
```

please let me know how to set default time.

Comment: You could add a default date. with a time: `new Date(2013, 11 - 1, 21),
                        "11/22/2013 00:53"`

Comment: i want only time to set 00:00, not date.

Comment: Try to leave the date out. There is no other way to set a default time.

Answer (score 0):

you can set format like this:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      language: 'en',
      pickTime: false,
      format: "dd/MM/yyyy 00:00:00"
    });
```